# Is there anyway we can extract text from image Axis wise only?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, tesseract, text-extraction

in  Attach image I want to extract text from the image (axis-wise only) i.e in first iteration return to me `sensitization time` and then y-axis text `DOS`... Does anyone knows about this how I can we do this??

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're looking for a recommendation for a tool to extract text from an image, this is not the appropriate place. There are other sources online...

Comment: hi, kindly can you tell me about the other online resources??